# Convert string to date in (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string to date format yyyy/mm/dd

```
string test="August 27 2014"; I want to convert to 2014/08/27
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). It is generally good to show what you tried and what specific problems you have with your question. It is also good to have an actual *question* in your question. SO is no code writing service.

Comment: Well, you want. What did you do for that?

Comment: Sorry. the problem is I want to add a day in string "August 27 2014" when clicking button. so i want to convert it first to yyyy/mm/dd format.

Comment: @nojla - That part was understood. What others are asking you is what have you tried so far?

Comment: Give a try to http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the string seems to be easily parsed by `date`

```
var yourDate = new Date('August 27 2014');
```

`yourDate` is the date object what you need,

then

```
yourDate.getFullYear() //get the yeaer number
yourDate.getMonth()+1  //get the month number
yourDate.getDate()   // get the date number
```

at last, try to [read it >>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: thanks!! no need to convert